# How to solve a system of nonlinear equations containing logarithm

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, nonlinear-system

I need to solve the following system of equations for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$
$$x_1= 0.64\times x_2 + 0.64\times x_3$$
$$x_5\times (x_2)^2= 0.392 - 1.25\times x_4 \times (x_1)^2$$
$$x_5\times(x_2)^2= 0.588 - 2.5\times x_6\times (x_3)^2$$
$$1/\sqrt x_4= -2\times log_{10}\left (\frac {3.15E-5}{x_1\times \sqrt x_4} \right)$$
$$1/\sqrt x_5= -2\times log_{10}\left (\frac {2.52E-5}{x_2\times \sqrt x_5}\right)$$
$$1/\sqrt x_6= -2\times log_{10}\left (\frac {3.15E-5}{x_3\times\sqrt x_6}\right)$$

I know Matlab has some commands like fsolve but I'm not sure if it applies in this case, and if it doesn't I want to know which numerical method works best to solve the system numerically

note: $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$ are float numbers and i'm interested in the solutions in which at least $x_4,x_5,x_6$ are positive real numbers (and $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are real)

thanks

Comment: Are these all float numbers?

Comment: Are you interested in all solutions?

Comment: Yes! these variables are float. x1,x2,x3 stand for velocity and x4,x5,x6 are friction factors

Comment: And my second question?

Comment: Just the ones that are positive values, at least for x4,x5,x6. thank you

Comment: Ok, I will try it for you!

Comment: Wow, my program has found the solutions, where should i post them?

Comment: is this a new system?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your last question, I think this system has been done before, I just couldn't find the way to approach the problem (researching on the internet). It's a fluid mechanics system of equations.

Comment: One moment i will check all again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93418/discussion-between-violeta-ayon-and-dr-sonnhard-graubner).

Answer (score 3):

You can clarify the system by a change of variable $y_k=x_k^2x_{k+3}$ for $k=1,2,3$ and $y_k=1/\sqrt{x_k}$ for $k=4,5,6$.

$$\begin{cases}y_4\sqrt{y_1}&= 0.64 y_5\sqrt{y_2} + 0.64 y_6\sqrt{y_3},
\\y_2&= 0.392 - 1.25y_1,
\\y_2&= 0.588 - 2.5y_3,
\\y_4&= a+\log_{10}y_1,
\\y_5&= b+\log_{10}y_2,
\\y_6&= c+\log_{10}y_3.
\end{cases}$$

Then if you express all unknowns in terms of $y_2$, you get a single equation in a single unknown

$$\left(a+\log_{10}\frac{0.392-y_2}{1.25}\right)\sqrt{\frac{0.392-y_2}{1.25}}=
\\ 0.64\left(b+\log_{10}y_2\right)\sqrt{y_2} + 0.64\left(c+\log_{10}\frac{0.588-y_2}{2.5}\right)\sqrt{\frac{0.588-y_2}{2.5}}.$$

Plot the function to check the number of solutions, then use a 1D solver. From $y_2$ you draw all $y$, then all $x$ in a straightforward way.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(9.0034%2Blog10((0.392-y)%2F(1.25)))sqrt((0.392-y)%2F(1.25))%3D+0.64(9.1972%2Blog10(y))%5Csqrt(y)+%2B+0.64(9.0034%2Blog10((0.588-y)%2F(2.5)))sqrt((0.588-y)%2F(2.5))

Comment: What is nice with your solution is that, starting at $y_2=0.196$, your function is almost a straight line and Newton method converges very fast to the solution.

Comment: This really helped me out, thank you for your time!

Comment: If we compute the values of the function at $y_2=0$ and $y_2=0.392$ and draw a straight line, the intercept is at $y_2=0.12$ !!!

Answer (score 2):

This system of equations can easily be reduced to two equations for two unknowns $x_2$ and $x_3$.

Fist, let
$x_i=\frac 1 {y_i^2}$ for $i=4,5,6$ and $k_4=k_6=3.15 \times 10^{-5}$, $k_5=2.52 \times 10^{-5}$.

Using the last three equations, we then have
$$y_4=\frac{2 W\left(\frac{x_1 \log (10)}{2 k_4}\right)}{\log (10)}\qquad y_5=\frac{2 W\left(\frac{x_2 \log (10)}{2 k_5}\right)}{\log (10)}\qquad y_6=\frac{2 W\left(\frac{x_3 \log (10)}{2 k_6}\right)}{\log (10)}$$ where appears Lambert functions. The first equation gives $x_1=0.64(x_2+x_3)$.

All of the above makes that remain the second and third equations which,
using your numbers and whole numbers everywhere, write
$$\frac{125 x_2^2}{W\left(\frac{1250000\log (10)}{63}  x_2\right)^2}+\frac{64
   (x_2+x_3)^2}{W\left(\frac{640000 \log (10)}{63} (x_2+x_3)\right)^2}=\frac{196}{\log ^2(10)}$$
$$ \frac{2 x_2^2}{W\left(\frac{1250000\log (10)}{63} x_2 \right)^2}+\frac{5
   x_3^2}{W\left(\frac{1000000\log (10)}{63}  x_3\right)^2}=\frac{588}{125 \log ^2(10)} $$
which do not seem to be possibly simplified.

Using Newton-Raphson method (initial guesses $x_2^{(0)}=x_3^{(0)}=1$), the calculations converge without any trouble to the solutions
$$x_2=2.6346572 \qquad \text{and} \qquad x_3=3.6519568$$ from which
$$x_1=4.0234330\qquad x_4=0.0142830\qquad x_5=0.0148360\qquad x_6=0.0145467$$

Comment: Our solutions seem to match ($x_2^2x_5\approx 0.10$).

Comment: @YvesDaoust. I was not able to reduce to a single variable ! It is good that you made it. I think that my initial mistake was to focus on Lambert. $\to +1$ for sure.

Comment: I know that Lambert is your good friend. By an old superstition, I would prefer not to use it inside an equation, as the solver will "emulate it" anyway. I was successful by observing the symmetries in the equations, and being obsessed to simplify ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I'm going ahead and solve those equations numerically. Also, the values you got by Newton-Raphson make sense physically for the problem I'm solving.